# PHP Force Download PDF Getts Corrupted in Opera Mini and Defaulot Android Browser

Tags: php, wordpress

I have implemented a PHP code that authenticates a user and then forces the pdf download using `readfile()`.

The code works well in desktop in all browsers (Chrome, mozilla and IE).

In mobile smartphones (Android), the script works only in three browsers; which are, mozilla,chrome and UC browser. In Opera mini and the default android browser the PDF is corrupted and when I view the corrupted files in notepad, I see only the html code.

How can I overcome this problem in Opera Mini and the default android browser?

Of course the document is located outside public_html in cpanel hence the need to force download.

Here is my code;

```
<?php
$file = "/home/mammitme/deeq/deeq_file.pdf"; //This simply specifies the path of the file to be read.
$fileName = explode("/", $file);
$fileName = end($fileName);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"'); //This tells the browser the name to use in the download.
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-type: application/pdf;");
ob_clean ();
readfile("$file");`
```

Comment: Hi. Have you figure out what was the issue? I'm facing similar thing on Opera Mini